# Strange array declaration in Java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

`Project[[ | ]] array = new Project[[1 | 1]];`

I am not getting which kind of array declaration is this?
Also I don't know if it is correct or not. I tried it in Netbeans but it is not allowed.
But in this example http://wiki.netbeans.org/OpenProjectsProgramaticallyInNetBeansIDE 
I found such example.

Give me some idea if it is correct.

Comment: It's not correct syntax. Seems to be a typo in the example code.

Comment: Is this java ? ouch!!!!! when they changed the array syntax ?

Comment: Android Killer I am also surprised when i Saw this first time.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be correct syntax, even with the latest Java 8 conventions. I think it's just a typo, as Kayaman says. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for documentation.

Comment: `Project[] array = new Project[1];` is what they meant in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid syntax.  See the Java Language Specification for the correct syntax for declaring an array.  [Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

The specification specifically states:

> An array initializer is written as a comma-separated list of
>   expressions, enclosed by braces { and }.

There is no mention of adding pipes or nesting brackets.

Answer (score 2):

According to `javac` from JDK7, it's invalid syntax (`error: illegal start of expression` pointing at the first `[[`). I assume it must be an error generating that page or some such.